# Cannot index empty buffer in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm following along with Rob Percival's tutorial on Udemy and my app crashes with a fatal error: cannot index empty buffer.

The error happens on the following line in the ViewdidLoad method:

```
userImage.image = UIImage(data: self.userImages[0])
```

Using `println(self.userImages)` right above that erroneous line I found out the array is empty. The console outputs a `[]`. This must be why it's crashing. Correct?

My Parse.com dashboard shows that all my users have images. I'm not sure why the array would be empty. Any ideas?

```
import UIKit

class SwipeViewController: UIViewController {


    var xFromCenter: CGFloat = 0

    var usernames = [String]()
    var userImages = [NSData]()
    var currentUser = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println(PFUser.currentUser()["first_name"])

        PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geopoint: PFGeoPoint!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            println(error)

            if error == nil {

                println(geopoint)

                var user = PFUser.currentUser()

                user["location"] = geopoint


                var query = PFUser.query()
                query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:geopoint)

                query.limit = 10
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (users, error) -> Void in

                    for user in users {

                        var gender1 = user["gender"] as? NSString
                        var gender2 = PFUser.currentUser()["interestedIn"] as? NSString

                        if gender1 == gender2 && PFUser.currentUser().username != user.username {

                            self.usernames.append(user.username)

                            // Update - chaned as to as!

                            self.userImages.append(user["image"] as NSData)

                        }


                    }

                    var userImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))
                    println("images:")
                    println(userImage)
                    println(self.userImages)

                    userImage.image = UIImage(data: self.userImages[0])
                    userImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
                    self.view.addSubview(userImage)

                    var gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDragged:"))
                    userImage.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

                    userImage.userInteractionEnabled = true



                })

                user.save()

            }

        }






    }

    func wasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {



        let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
        var label = gesture.view!

        xFromCenter += translation.x

        var scale = min(100 / abs(xFromCenter), 1)

        label.center = CGPoint(x: label.center.x + translation.x, y: label.center.y + translation.y)

        gesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

        var rotation:CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(xFromCenter / 200)

        var stretch:CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(rotation, scale, scale)

        label.transform = stretch

        if label.center.x < 100 {

            println("Not Chosen")

        } else if label.center.x > self.view.bounds.width - 100 {

            println("Chosen")

        }

        if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

            self.currentUser++

            label.removeFromSuperview()

            if self.currentUser < self.userImages.count {

                var userImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))
                userImage.image = UIImage(data: self.userImages[self.currentUser])
                userImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
                self.view.addSubview(userImage)

                var gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDragged:"))
                userImage.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

                userImage.userInteractionEnabled = true

                xFromCenter = 0

            } else {

                println("No more users")

            }

        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a data issue. The problem must comes from the loop just above the failing line.

Conditions are not met, and so no image is pushed into the array. Reasons can be:

- You only have 1 user (your current user)
- There is no other users with a gender that meets the "interested in" condition of your current user
- Your users (current or not) doesn't have the "gender" or "interestedIn" attributes set

The best way is to put breakpoint (or log) inside your loop in order to determine users gender and "interestedIn" attributes and see if there is some matches.

Comment: That was it! I feel so stupid now. I had gender set to "male" or "female" and then my interestedin attribute had values of "men", "women", and "both". Thank you so much for the help. I'm going to try using breakpoints next time. I need to get into that debugging mindset!